# Não consigo extrair as informações do Json no Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

Eu recebo uma request assim...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

A saída é essa:

```
anexoPdfGuia: {}

guiaFiscal: "{"empresas_id":"40","tributo_id":4,"mes_referencia":4,"vencimento":"2018-05-10","email":"carlos.boschin@gmail.com","titulo":"teste666","tributo":{"id":4,"nome":"PIS"},"mesReferencia":{"id":4,"nome":"Abril"},"data_vencimento":"2018-05-10T03:00:00.000Z","valor":1.11}"
```

Preciso pegar um atributo dentro de guia fiscal, mas não estou conseguindo com o json_decode.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Voce quer que o PHP leia o resultado do Laravel?

Comment: Não. Essa $request ta vindo em JSON.stringify. Eu quero saber como eu desmembro ela, pra obter um parâmetro que está vindo dentro dela e o Josn_decode, não está dando certo...

Comment: Como realmente estao chegando os dados no metodo store()?

Comment: Isso é uma requisição ajax? Esse return envia os dados para algum JS?

Answer (score 2):

Com o json_decode deveria funcionar, tem certeza que esta usando da forma correta?

Exemplo:

```
$json = '{"empresas_id":"40","tributo_id":4,"mes_referencia":4,"vencimento":"2018-05-10","email":"carlos.boschin@gmail.com","titulo":"teste666","tributo":{"id":4,"nome":"PIS"},"mesReferencia":{"id":4,"nome":"Abril"},"data_vencimento":"2018-05-10T03:00:00.000Z","valor":1.11}';
$object = json_decode($json);
echo $object->empresas_id; // vai imprimir 40
```

Comment: $json = json_decode($request);  return response($json->empresas_id); Fiz dessa forma...

Comment: tem como você dar um var_dump no $request e me mostrar oque exatamente esta sendo enviado para o json_decode, e também de que forma está tentando acessar a variavel?

Comment: Se eu uso                                                                             
        $requestArray = json_decode($request);
        return response()->json($requestArray);                                               Ele me retorna { }.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que você está mostrando no seu retorno

```
 '{"empresas_id":"40","tributo_id":4,"mes_referencia":4,"vencimento":"2018-05-10","email":"carlos.boschin@gmail.com","titulo":"teste666","tributo":{"id":4,"nome":"PIS"},"mesReferencia":{"id":4,"nome":"Abril"},"data_vencimento":"2018-05-10T03:00:00.000Z","valor":1.11}';
```

Se seu retorno está sendo como retornado acima então ele já é um objeto, bastando apenas você obter o atributo, assim:

```
 public function inicio( Request $request ){
      $retorno = json_decode( $request->input( 'dados' ) );
      return response()->json( ["mes" => $retorno->mes_referencia]  );
}
```

Do jeito que está no exemplo eu enviei uma string direto, pode ser que seja seu caso:

```
           $('.btn').on('click', function(){
                clique();
            });

            function clique(){
                $.ajax( {
                    url : '{{ route('dados') }}',
                    type : 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        _token : '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                        dados : '{"empresas_id":"40","tributo_id":4,"mes_referencia":4,"vencimento":"2018-05-10","email":"carlos.boschin@gmail.com","titulo":"teste666","tributo":{"id":4,"nome":"PIS"},"mesReferencia":{"id":4,"nome":"Abril"},"data_vencimento":"2018-05-10T03:00:00.000Z","valor":1.11}'
                    },
                    success: function( data ){
                        $('.saida').text( data );
                    }
                } );
            }
```

Espero que ajude.